# Using setSample with WritableRaster

Tags: java, bufferedimage, raster

I want to remove particular color, and when I set

```
 wrres.setSample(x, y, 0, wrsrc.getSample(x, y, 0)) ;
```

I don't have error but when I set something else like 
  `wrres.setSample(x, y, 1, wrsrc.getSample(x, y, 1)) ;` then I've got

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Coordinate out of bounds!
    at java.awt.image.MultiPixelPackedSampleModel.getSample(MultiPixelPackedSampleModel.java:359)
    at java.awt.image.Raster.getSample(Raster.java:1648)
```

it gives me the same image (just copied)
 `BufferedImage imres = user_space(img,1);`

```
int height = img.getHeight();
            int width = img.getWidth();

            BufferedImage imsrc = img; // The source image, RGBA
            BufferedImage imres = user_space(img,1);  // The resulting image, RGB or BGR 
            WritableRaster wrsrc = imsrc.getRaster() ;
            WritableRaster wrres = imres.getRaster() ;

            for (int y=0 ; y < img.getHeight() ; y++)
                for (int x=0 ; x < img.getWidth() ; x++)
                {
                    wrres.setSample(x, y, 0, wrsrc.getSample(x, y, 0)) ;
                    wrres.setSample(x, y, 1, wrsrc.getSample(x, y, 1)) ;
                    wrres.setSample(x, y, 2, wrsrc.getSample(x, y, 2)) ;
                }
    return 
     new BufferedImage(imsrc.getColorModel(),wrres,imsrc.getColorModel().isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);
        }
```

How to use setSample to set different colors not only black and white(band equal to 0 ) '

I don't want to use getRGB from  BufferedImage

Comment: There is a misconception here, that band == color channel. While it might be for some image types (using `BandedSampleModel`), it is not the case usually. As your image (from the stack trace) use `MultiPixelPackedSampleModel`, it's most likely `TYPE_INT_ARGB`. This type of layout has only one "band". And each "sample" is the 32 bit ARGB value. For `TYPE_3BYTE_BGR` (using `PixelInterleavedSampleModel`), as an example, you still have only one band, while each sample is three 8 bit values.

Comment: Thanks for answer :). So is there possibility to extract color without bit shifting?